# SAS Programming: Create New Column base on Suffix of Existing Column

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a sas dataset called list that contains all files/path/filename of a directory.

[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfOsu.png)

I want to create a new column base on the suffix of column **the_name** to add 1, so 01 will become 02 and 02 will become 03.

For example:

the_name: FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042002 

new_name: FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042003


the_name: FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042101 

new_name: FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042102

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you known the functions `SCAN`, `INPUT`, and `CATS` ?

Comment: Got it! 

data TEST (drop = X);
 set list;
 X = put(input(substr(the_name,length(the_name),1),8.)+1,8.);
 new_name = compress(substr(the_name,1,length(the_name)-1)||X);
run;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recy:

A safer increment would be to scan then entire number off the end of `the _name`, and not rely on incrementing just a single tail end digit.

```
data _null_;
  the_name = 'FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042002';

  suffix = scan(the_name,-1,'_');
  nextnum = input(suffix,best20.)+1;
  new_name = cats(transtrn(the_name,trim(suffix),''),nextnum);

  put the_name= / new_name= ;
run;
--- LOG ---
the_name=FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042002
new_name=FOR_PROCESSING_1234562020042003
```